# Add attribute after existing one

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, addition

I'm trying to add an attribute after an existing one, but I really don't understand.

The XML format.

```
<table name="spelers">
  <column name="ID">4565</column>
  <column name="Voornaam">Ivo</column>
  <column name="Achternaam">Dolman</column>
  <column name="SchoolID">5811</column>
</table>
```

What I try to do, if

> column name="Tussenvoegsel">

does not exist is to add it after "Voornaam"

```
<table name="spelers">
  <column name="ID">4565</column>
  <column name="Voornaam">Ivo</column>
  <column name="Tussenvoegsel"></column>
  <column name="Achternaam">Dolman</column>
  <column name="SchoolID">5811</column>
</table>
```

My code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Users\-\Desktop\Niuew\spelersOUD.xml");

XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Voornaam");
XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("Tussenvoegsel");
id.SetAttribute("Tussenvoegsel", "");
root.AppendChild(id);
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\-\Desktop\Niuew\output.xml");
```

Help is much appreciated, I probably get confused of Elements and Nodes, Root...

Comment: That is adding an *element*, not an *attribute*; what happens currently - does it fail? does it add at the wrong position? (at the end maybe)?

Comment: I literally see no difference, I get confused what an element is what an attribute is.

Comment: `<thisIsAnElement thisIsAnAttribute="attribute value">with element body</thisIsAnElement>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

- identify the node you want to insert after - using `SelectSingleNode`, for example
- create a new element (like you did with `id`)
- use `InsertAfter` on the *parent* of where you want it added - i.e. `<table>`, the root node

Something like

```
var table = doc.DocumentElement;
var voornaam = (XmlElement)table.SelectSingleNode("*[@name='Voornaam']");
XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement("column");
newElement.SetAttribute("name", "Tussenvoegsel");
table.InsertAfter(newElement, voornaam);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the node Tussenvoegsel after Voornaam only if it does not already exists you should do something like this:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Users\-\Desktop\Niuew\spelersOUD.xml");
        var table = doc.ChildNodes[0];
        var voornaam = (XmlElement)table.SelectSingleNode("*[@name='Voornaam']");
        var tussenvoegsel = (XmlElement)table.SelectSingleNode("*[@name='Tussenvoegsel']");
        if (tussenvoegsel == null)
        {
            XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement("column");
            newElement.SetAttribute("name", "Tussenvoegsel");
            table.InsertAfter(newElement, voornaam);
        }
        doc.Save(@"C:\Users\-\Desktop\Niuew\output.xml");
```

Comment: Nice, I'm getting the idea unfortantly I get an exception

`System.InvalidOperationException
The current node can not contain other nodes`